# Receiving an unknown provider error while trying to unit test angular 1.5 components

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-components, grunt-contrib-jasmine

So I'm unit testing a component I made with Angular 1.5. For security purposes, I can't copy and paste that code here, but I can give some mocks.

It's a simple component that has some basic selection action, with an binding event when something is selected.

So the code would look like this:

```
angular
      .module( "myModule" )
      .component( "myComponent", { 
       template: "Some random HTML Template",
       bindings: { 
         onSelect: "&" 
       },
       controller: function () {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.$onInit = init;
        ctrl.selection = selection; 
        function init() {}  function selection() { 
             ctrl.onSelect(ctrl.selected) } 
       } } );
```

That's the basic component. I'm trying to unit test it, with a format such as this:

```
describe( "Component Test", function() { 
    beforeEach (module( "myModule") ); 
    var ctrl, onSelectSpy;
    beforeEach (inject( function( _$componentController_) { 
    ctrl = {}
    onSelectSpy = jasmine.createSpy("onSelect");
    var $componentController = _$componentController_;
    ctrl = $componentController("myComponent", null, { onSelect: 
onSelectSpy}); 
    } ) ); 

    it ("Controller defined", function() { 
    ctrl.$onInit(); 
   expect ( ctrl ).toBeDefined(); 
  }); 
} );
```

When I try running a test that looks very similar to this, I get this error:

Unknown provider: myComponentDirectiveProvider <- myComponentDirective
And it gives an angular url about the line where it fails.

Not sure why it's not getting defined and why this isn't working. I thought components were directives.

Using Angular 1.5.8 and Angular-mocks 1.5.8

Comment: it sounds like angular can't find the component. is the `myModule` module loaded properly in the spec file? any typos?